Dowling versus Rote
Ranieri-Dowling Method Versus the Rote Method of Learning.
Are these two methods of pedagogy dissimilar? They appear to be similar from a basis overview of each approach.
I’m trying to determine the best method in which someone can consume Latin. As of yet, I’m using a loosely defined version of Ranieri-Dowling’s Method. Meaning I’ve also used an immersive technique, in as far as watching “Minecraftium in lingua Latina” goes.

Are you more interested in the explanation of the methods? Because then this might be better over at Language Learning. If you in particular want to see which method is better for you for learning Latin, can you then add to your question why you want to learn Latin? Just like with any language, the purpose will inform which method(s) to use.

Thank you. I’ll look into it.
I’m preparing for a Master’s in Latin. I have a year to get ready for an entrance exam for said program. Thereby, I’m learning Latin with the intention to read classic text, ecclesiastical studies, and eventually teaching Latin (read and spoken).

Welcome to the site! You could add explanation to your question. In addition, you might want to explain what the two methods entail.
